# Solution of $n!=p+1 $ with $p$ is prime number?

Tags: factorial, prime-factorization

One of my friend asked me to solve this equation  $n!=p+1 $ with $p$ is prime number  and n is positive integer , it's clear that for $p=2$ there is no solutions because : $n! < 3$ for $n=1$ , But what about $p >2$ ? Probably the solution of that equation w'd be satisfied with Mersann primes of the form $2^{p'}-1$ with $p'\neq 11$ , The reason i have got is $p=2^{p'}-1$ is a solution of $n!=p+1 $ because $n!$ never be a perfect square .

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A002982](https://oeis.org/A002982) and links there.

Comment: For $n \le 25$,  the only values which satisfy the condition are $n=3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 14$  (the last two lead to prime p with high probability but not with certainty because I used emacs calc for the calculation and it uses a probabilistic primality algorithm for "large" numbers).

Comment: $12!-1$ and $14!-1$ are prime according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com)

Comment: look the above comment by @NickD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine some values $n!$ and try subtracting 1 from each of them:
$$
3! - 1 = 5, \;\mbox{a prime}
$$
$$
4! - 1 = 23, \;\mbox{a prime}
$$
$$
6! - 1 = 719, \;\mbox{a prime}
$$
$$
7! - 1 = 5039, \;\mbox{a prime}.
$$

Comment: By brute force $12!-1$ has no divisor >1 equal to or below its square root --> prime.